# ASP Core 2.1 - Query gets interrupted by server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server

I need to make an async POST request to a part of my API, and the query is taking around 30 minutes.

When I try on local it works fine both on Debug and Release, but when I am publishing to my hosting provider, the request gets interrupted after around 2 minutes, and the server responds with error 500 or 502.

I already tried to add the following lines to my `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <aspNetCore requestTimeout="10:00:00">
    <environmentVariables />
  </aspNetCore>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="fr-FR" culture="fr-FR" />
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="10000" />
</system.web>
```

And also to modify the request timeout via Kestrel options in `Program.cs`:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel(o => { o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1); });
```

With no effects unfortunatly. What can I do to not have my query interrupted?

Comment: sounds like you should have an async operation - who's your hosting provider? what's their configuration?

Comment: @DanielA.White the API method is `async`. This is an AJAX request. My hosting provider is ionos (formerly 1&1), and I am on a shared Windows hosting

Comment: @DanielA.White also, the servers responds with error 502

Comment: i'd contact their support to get some logs.